# I Can get a Group Album photos, but not a group photos, why?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying make a backup of my group, and i try get all group photos with:

```
"<GroupID>/photos"
```

but the graph returns:

```
"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (photos) on node type (Group)"
```

but with a Album of the group, he return the pictures... why this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get photos from Facebook's API after version 2.0 deprecates (which is on Aug 8th, 2016). If you see their docs it shows that that edge/endpoint can't be read any longer after version 2.0: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/group/photos

It's possible to use FQL, but this only works until version 2.0 is deprecated, which is in a few weeks.

Comment: I got "(#200) Insufficient permission to post to group" error